# ValidationError when trying to create an object in mongodb

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, axios

When trying to send request via axios to backend(mongodb) , throws validation error. and this only happens while trying to create product via front-end. i tried creating product via Postman and it works fine.
**Addproductpage**

> Error: ValidationError: quantity: Path `quantity` is required., brand: Path `brand` is required., category: Path `category` is required., price: Path `price` is required., description: Path `description` is required., slug: Path `slug` is required., title: Path `title` is required.
> at C:\Users\Desktop\backend\controller\productControler.js:171:11

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useDropzone } from 'react-dropzone';
import axios from 'axios';
import config from "../app/utils/axiosconfig";

const AddProduct = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [productName, setProductName] = useState('');
  const [description, setDescription] = useState('');
  const [price, setPrice] = useState('');
  const [brand, setBrand] = useState('');
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState('');
  const [color, setColor] = useState('');
  const [uploadedImage, setUploadedImage] = useState(null);

  const onDrop = (acceptedFiles) => {
    // Process the uploaded file here
    const uploadedFile = acceptedFiles[0];
    setUploadedImage(uploadedFile);
  };

  const { getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive } = useDropzone({ onDrop });

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    
    // Create a new FormData object
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('productName', productName);
    formData.append('description', description);
    formData.append('price', price);
    formData.append('brand', brand);
    formData.append('quantity', quantity);
    formData.append('color', color);
    formData.append('image', uploadedImage);

    // Make a POST request to your backend API
     axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/products/', formData,config)
      .then((response) => {
         // Handle successful form submission
         console.log('Product added successfully');
       })
       .catch((error) => {
         // Handle error
        console.log('Error adding product', error);
       });
   
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Add Product</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label>Product Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={productName}
            onChange={(e) => setProductName(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Description</label>
          <textarea
            value={description}
            onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Price</label>
          <input
            type="number"
            value={price}
            onChange={(e) => setPrice(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Brand</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={brand}
            onChange={(e) => setBrand(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Quantity</label>
          <input
            type="number"
            value={quantity}
            onChange={(e) => setQuantity(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Color</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={color}
            onChange={(e) => setColor(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Image</label>
          <div {...getRootProps()} className="dropzone">
            <input {...getInputProps()} />
            {isDragActive ? (
              <p>Drop the files here...</p>
            ) : (
              <p>Drag and drop an image here, or click to select a file</p>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Add Product</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddProduct;
```

[the values from front end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNCtE.png)[the error][success in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuR0G.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCmuq.png)

I am trying to create a product,

**product model**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose"); // Erase if already required

// Declare the Schema of the Mongo model
var productSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    slug: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      lowercase: true,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    price: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    category: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    brand: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    quantity: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    sold: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    images: [
      {
        public_id: String,
        url: String,
      },
    ],
    color: [],
    tags: String,
    ratings: [
      {
        star: Number,
        comment: String,
        postedby: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
      },
    ],
    totalrating: {
      type: String,
      default: 0,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

//Export the model
module.exports = mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);
```

**product controller**

```
const createProduct = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (req.body.title) {
      req.body.slug = slugify(req.body.title);
    }
    const newProduct = await Product.create(req.body);
    res.json(newProduct);
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }
});
```

btw i'm new to web development,apologies for poor representation of the problem. thanks